# Run code after loop in background ends

Tags: xcode, swift, multithreading

I am running background thread in a while loop where I am doing some file handling task. I have some code after the loop. But the codes after the loop being executed before the loop ends (cause I am using background thread). Is there any way I can execute some code exactly after the loop ends?

Here is my code:

```
while i < testCount {
    let task = AsyncTask(
        backgroundTask: {
            () -> Double in
            // some file handling
            return 234.09

        },
        afterTask: {
            (val: Double) in
            self.showVal(val)
        }
    );
    task.execute();

    i += 1
}

// I want to run this code after the loop ends
print("average: \(avg)")
showVal(avg)
```

My `showVal(Double)` function

```
func showVal(val: Double) {
    print("val found: \(val)")
    display.text = "\(val) found"
}
```

And here is my `AsyncTask` class

```
public class AsyncTask <BGParam,BGResult>{
    private var pre:(()->())?;//Optional closure -> called before the backgroundTask
    private var bgTask:(param:BGParam)->BGResult;//background task
    private var post:((param:BGResult)->())?;//Optional closure -> called after the backgroundTask

    public init(beforeTask: (()->())?=nil, backgroundTask: (param:BGParam)->BGResult, afterTask:((param:BGResult)->())?=nil){
        self.pre=beforeTask;
        self.bgTask=backgroundTask;
        self.post=afterTask;
    }

    public func execute(param:BGParam){
        pre?()//if beforeTask exists - invoke it before bgTask
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), {
            let bgResult=self.bgTask(param: param);//execute backgroundTask in background thread
            if(self.post != nil){//if afterTask exists - invoke it in UI thread after bgTask
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{self.post!(param: bgResult)});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: I am a beginner in `Swift`.

**Edit:**
I actually want to do:

1. A background file handling task
2. After the task ends, I want to show a text in a UILabel

I need to do this two tasks several times (say 100 times). If swift has easier methods for my purpose, please advise.

Comment: The pragmatic option would simply be to have an if-check on your counter and execute the code from this. Also on a small swift-code-style note, I'd suggest using `for i in 0..<testCount` rather than `while` (if you need to use a counter variable at all, that is).

Comment: Okay. Can you please see my edits, I mentioned my actual purpose.

Comment: So, let me see if I got this correct. You need to perform a background file-handling taks an unknown number of times, and when all of these have been completed you want to do something else(?)

Comment: Very close. I want to do a task several times, say 100 times (known). The task has two parts: 1. File handling - Background Thread, and 2. Display a text in the `UILabel` - UI Thread. Remember this two parts makes a complete task and this complete task should execute 100 times. After this 100 times has been completed, I want to do something else.

Comment: From the top of my head I think I would probably have a Manager/Coordinator type object being fed the information about the number of calls required and dealing with the actual networkRequests. This object would have a "completionClosure"-property and then check internally if the required number of calls had been reached and perform the completionClosure if this was the case.

Comment: I think what you mentioned is a very good way to go. But as a beginner, I need example/tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try with some pseudo-code based our discussion to see if that might help you on the way. The manager-object would probably look a little something like this:

```
class RequestManager {
    private let requiredNumberOfRequests: Int
    private let completionHandler: ()->()
    private var counter: Int {
        didSet {
            if counter == requiredNumberOfRequests {
                completionHandler()
            }
        }
    }

    init(numberOfRequests: Int, completionHandler: ()->()) {
        self.requiredNumberOfRequests = numberOfRequests
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        self.counter = 0
    }

    // Don't know exactly what you want to do here, but something like...
    func performRequest(success: (value: Double)->()) {
        // Network stuff, on success it looks like you'll have a Double(?)
        let value: Double = 234.09
        success(value: value)
        counter += 1
    }
}
```

Then, before your loop you'll create an instance of the requestManager

```
let manager = RequestManager(numberOfRequests: 100) { average in
    print("average: \(average)")
}
```

...and call the performRequest as part of your loop.